# How can I use IAM policies to gain fine-grained access control for DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

I'm currently experimenting with [Amazon DynamoDB](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/) to create a full JavaScript application directly in browser using the [AWS SDK for JavaScript in the Browser](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforbrowser/).
But, I can't manage to secure access to DynamoDB.

In `IAM` I created a Group named `Users` with this policy :

```js
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [{
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
        "dynamodb:BatchWriteItem",
        "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
        "dynamodb:GetItem",
        "dynamodb:PutItem",
        "dynamodb:Query",
        "dynamodb:UpdateItem"
      ],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-1:1234567891234:table/*"],
      "Condition": {
        "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
          "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": ["${aws:username}"]}
    }
  }]
}
```

I have a user named `Bahaika` who belongs to the `Users` group.

In DynamoDB I created two items :

```
-------------------------
|  Dog ID  |   User Id  |
-------------------------
|   Dog1   |  Bahaika   |
-------------------------
|   Dog2   | NotBahaika |
-------------------------
```

I'd like to be able to only get Dog1, but not Dog2 when I'm logged with the `Access Key ID` and `Secret Access Key` of Bahaika.

I also want to automatically add the `User ID` attributes when an item is added to the table.
And, finally, I want to be able to list all the items of the tables where `User ID` is equals to the logged one.

**How can I manage to do that ?**

I already read [Fine-Grained Access Control for DynamoDB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/FGAC_DDB.html)
but I think I've missed something.

Comment: What is not working specifically, do you see both or no dog when logged in as _Bahaika_ (sounds like the former, but to clarify)?

Comment: I've an `AccessDenied` for both dogs. When I disable the policy I can access to all dogs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [IAM Condition](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/AccessPolicyLanguage_ElementDescriptions.html#Condition) `dynamodb:LeadingKeys` is using the regular [IAM policy variable](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/PolicyVariables.html) `${aws:username}`, which is not present when using [Web Identity Federation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WIF.html), see the table within [Request Information That You Can Use for Policy Variables](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/PolicyVariables.html#policy-vars-infotouse). Instead you'll need to use `${www.amazon.com:user_id}` as referenced in [Fine-Grained Access Control for DynamoDB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/FGAC_DDB.html) and also the various [Example Policies for Fine-Grained Access Control](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/FGAC_DDB.Examples.html).

Comment: Am I using the Web Identity Federation when I hardcode the access key id, and secret access key ? I don't really understand the role of the `dynamodb:LeadingKeys`. And how can I find out what's the user_id of an user inside IAM console ?

Comment: Ah, no, I overlooked that aspect and simply concluded you would due to this being the only safe approach for using the AWS SDK for JavaScript in the Browser for anything bur read operations, sorry. Are you sure you only ever want to get read access to the table and thus can risk to hard-code AWS credentials in your JavaScript app?

Comment: Maybe I missed something about security : this is how I was imagining the system : first the user logged on my website, my website gives him back the AKID and SAK (for his account) and he uses it to connect to the dynamodb in a secured way (with read/write operations). Is this approach wrong ?

Comment: That's not safe due to in browser JavaScript applications being prone to all sorts of attacks - explaining those is out of scope here, but see section _Loading Credentials in the Client's Browser_ within [Configuring the SDK in the Browser](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-configuring.html) for an autoritative statement from AWS confirming that hard-coding is only safe if you constrain your app to read-only credentials. And **even then** those credentials could be hijacked by other users to read information they are not supposed to have access to.

Comment: So, no matter what approach I use, JavaScript on client side isn't safe ? Do I have to fallback on a "WebService" approach for security ?
Is "Login with Amazon" will force my users to have an Amazon Account ? Or it'll be just the accounts in my IAM console ? Because I want to handle accounts for payments etc...

Comment: You have a point about how you imagine your system though: this approach will work conceptually when using [Temporary Security Credentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/UsingSTS/Welcome.html) (aka a session token) to mitigate the attack surface etc., however, as outlined AWS is only supporting highly credited 3rd party vendors via Web Identity Federation at this point, so you'll need o resort to one of those. Alternatively you can also look into [AWS Identity and Access Management Using SAML](http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-identity-and-access-management-using-saml/).

Comment: Unfortuantely that's the case, see [Javascript Cryptography Considered Harmful](http://matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/) if you are up for a long read. You'll either need to use Web Identity Federation to log in with Amazon, Google or Facebook, or use a 3rd party SAML solution instead.  *In theory*, you could also implement the use of temporary security credentials yourself (after all, that's what the others do to in the end), however, that's a fairly complex thing to do and the general assumption is that nobody but highly specialized cryptography experts will get security right.

Comment: I will try to use Web Identity Federation to see if it can fit my needs but I think I will fallback on a WebService approach, those systems are too opaque for me and the security is a real matter for my web application.
I'll mark this question answered.
Thank you for everything :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can authenticate your user using their Amazon, Facebook, or Google credentials then you can use web identity federation which (in simple terms) will exchange a token from one of those 3 providers with temporary AWS security credentials that your app can use to access DynamoDB.  There are a few articles worth reading on this topic in the AWS documentation.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-configuring-wif.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WIF.html